# juju-gui - Not working

Tags: juju

I am working on a pyBossa project. I installed an Ubuntu server and also am using vagrant along with Juju. I need to install juju-gui. Here is what I did -

```
juju deploy juju-gui
juju status
```

I am not able to find an address of juju-gui. Status is just the following

```
services:
juju-gui:
charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-142
exposed: false
service-status:
  current: unknown
  message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish
  since: 24 May 2017 21:02:57Z
```

What is happenning incorrectly. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show a complete output of the `juju status` commando? Also... which version of juju are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Juju 2 you don't need to deploy the GUI charm any longer, it's included with Juju.

You can start the GUI by running `juju gui` and it'll output a link to the GUI as well as credentials you can use to log in.

If you've been running your controller for a while you can run `juju upgrade-gui` to upgrade to the latest GUI.